# Delete Django QuerySet objects with a duplicate value in a particular field

Tags: django, django-cms, django-queryset, django-shell

I have this Django model (from Django CMS):

```
class Placeholder(models.Model):
    slot = models.CharField(_("slot"), max_length=50, db_index=True)
    default_width = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(_("width"), null=True)
```

I want to delete the Placeholder objects with a duplicate 'slot' value, keeping only the first one of each and deleting the others.

How do I write a query (using the Django QuerySet API) that does this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would do a functional approach, rather than one particular query which does all of this:

```
existing_slots = []
for placeholder in Placeholder.objects.all():
    if placeholder.slot in existing_slots:
        placeholder.delete()
    else:
        existing_slots.append(placeholder.slot)
```

Answer (score 5):

You can try Torsten solution but using a dictionary instead, is way much faster.

```
existing_slots = {}
for placeholder in Placeholder.objects.all():
    if existing_slots.get(placeholder.slot, False):
        placeholder.delete()
    else:
        existing_slots[placeholder.slot] = True
```

Comment: While you are at it, why not using a `set()` instead and drop the `True`. If it's efficiency you are after, a `set()` is more efficient from a memory point of view than a dictionary.